# Cant update a UITableView data depending on the selector from UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I'm working on an app who shows news deppending on the section of the new. To select the sections I use a UIPickerView and show in a UITableView the news of the section selected.
Backend I use 2 NSMutable array, one of them is for save all the news and other is to save the news filtered for the section selection. 
Everything is OK, but when I select a section my method filters the news and load in the array but the tableview didn't reload the data and when I reload the tableview the app crash.
Anyone knows who to reload all the cells of the tableview when I select a new secction.

This is some of my code.

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [super viewDidLoad];

         arraySecciones = @[@"Todas",@"Agua Potable",@"Agua Residual",@"Centro I+D+I",@"Cooperacion",@"Residuos"];
         seccionesPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

         NSDate *fecha = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1431231];

         arrayNoticias = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 1" body:@"Cuerpo 1" section:@"Agua Potable" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 2" body:@"Cuerpo 2" section:@"Residuos" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 3" body:@"Cuerpo 3" section:@"Cooperacion" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 4" body:@"Cuerpo 4" section:@"Cooperacion" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 5" body:@"Cuerpo 5" section:@"Cooperacion" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 6" body:@"Cuerpo 6" section:@"Agua Potable" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 7" body:@"Cuerpo 7" section:@"Agua Residuale" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 8" body:@"Cuerpo 8" section:@"Agua Potable" date:fecha]];
         [arrayNoticias addObject:[[Noticia alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noticia 9" body:@"Cuerpo 9" section:@"Centro I+D+I" date:fecha]];

         seccionSelecccionada = @"Todas";
         arrayNoticiasFiltrado = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         [self getNoticiasArrayForSeccion];

     }

      - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
      {
          NSLog(@"Fila Seleccionada %ld",(long)row);

          switch (row) {
             case 0:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Todas";
                  break;
              case 1:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Agua Potable";
                  break;
              case 2:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Agua Residual";
                  break;
              case 3:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Centro I+D+I";
                  break;
              case 4:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Cooperacion";
                  break;
              case 5:
                  self.seccionSelecccionada = @"Residuos";
                  break;
          }

          seccionLabel.text = seccionSelecccionada;
          [self getNoticiasArrayForSeccion];
     }

     -(void)getNoticiasArrayForSeccion
     {
         [self.arrayNoticiasFiltrado removeAllObjects];

         for(int x=0; x<arrayNoticias.count; x++)
         {
           Noticia *noticiaAux = [arrayNoticias objectAtIndex:x];

            if ([self.seccionSelecccionada isEqualToString:@"Todas"])

                 [arrayNoticiasFiltrado addObject:noticiaAux];

             else if([noticiaAux.seccion isEqualToString:self.seccionSelecccionada])
                     [arrayNoticiasFiltrado addObject:noticiaAux];
         }
     }

     -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         Noticia *noticiaAux = [[Noticia alloc] init];

         noticiaAux = [arrayNoticiasFiltrado objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];
         NoticiasTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"celdaNoticias"];

         if(!cell)
             cell =[[NoticiasTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"celdaNoticias"];

         cell.titular.text = noticiaAux.titular;
         cell.seccion.text = noticiaAux.seccion;

         NSLog(@"Pintando : %@",cell.titular.text);
         return  cell;
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS8c8.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8pIl.png

Comment: From which array you are getting the data and displaying it into the tableview?

Comment: You need to call `reloadData` method of your tableview in order to tell the table to reload the data again from the array.

Comment: post the error you received. Its critically important to your question

Comment: I'm getting the data from arrayNoticias, later I filter it by the section and the filtered "Noticias" are added to arrayNoticiasFiltrado who is the NSMutableArray that I shows in the IUTableView.

Comment: The error recived when I drag the tableview the IndexPath.row is bigger than the arrayNoticiasFiltrado.count and when I get the first objectAtIndex:indexPath.row it crashes, because the indexPath.row is not updated to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the problem is you are reinitiating UITableView in ViewController.m file. You dont need to reinitiate tableview if you connect the outlet to the interface file.

In `-(void)getNoticiasArrayForSeccion` there is no need to allocate the object. You can simply get an object in ivar directly without allocating it.

Just call 
`[noticiasTable reloadData]`

at the end of your function

`-(void)getNoticiasArrayForSeccion` like this:

```
-(void)getNoticiasArrayForSeccion
{
    .... // loading data according to the filter selected

    [noticiasTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I already did it but did't reload the cells of the UITableView

Comment: @KurroCantos it would be really helpful if you share some code snippets with me.

Comment: I dont know how to do it, but I think this is the best way. I uploaded the project to GitHub : https://github.com/KurroCantos/newsPickerExample.git

Comment: @KurroCantos let me look into that and update you regarding the issue.

Comment: @KurroCantos NoticiasTableViewCell.h and .m file is missing along with Noticia.h and .m please upload the project again.

Comment: @KurroCantos please download the code from this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20020679/newsPickerExample%20%28Modified%29.zip

Comment: @KurroCantos also edit the post what was going wrong. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Comment: Men you are awesome!!! Thanks for the help, looks that I made a little mistake but I dont know how to solve it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @KurroCantos Pleasure is all mine. Please vote up the answer also :)

Comment: sorry I cant vote up , I dont have enought reputation.